# Prove/Disprove: When $A,B,C$ are symmetric matrices, the transpose of $ABC$ is $CBA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Prove/Disprove the following: When $A,B,C$ are symmetric matrices, the transpose of $ABC$ is $CBA$

This was what I did:

$$\text{Symmetric}   \ A,B,C \implies (A^T = A) \land (B^T = B) \land (C^T = C) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
$$(ABC)^T = C^TB^TA^T = CBA \ \ \ \  \ \ \text{(By (1))} $$

But according to the solutions manual $$(ABC)^T = C^TB^TA^T \neq CBA$$
Why would that be so?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. I would not try to guess the reason for the error in the manual.

Comment: A typo in the manual? Maybe it was ment to ask something like  "transpose of $ABC$ is $ABC$".

Comment: I also agree - as far as I can tell, this must be an error in the manual.